# How to read 1 record from a sql server database into a c# textbox?

Tags: c#, sql-server

I want to do this (on Form3):

```
sqlcon.Open();
            string selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM InvoiceTable where id = @id";
            SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlcon);
            sqldr = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader();
            while(sqldr.Read())
            {
                textbox1 = Max value of TotalCostColumn.value
                or
                textbox1 = Latest value of TotalCostColumn.value
                or
                textbox1 = 2nd row of TotalCostColumn.value
            }
```

Im not having any `datagridview` on this form. I do have a `datagridview` on `Form1` which is the actual invoice form. `Form3` is the confrimation form which lets the user confirm how much customer should pay eventually. I want the `TotalCostColumn`'s value from my database to be transfered in the related textbox in `Form3`.

Comment: Don't execute a SqlReader if you only need one value. Use ExecuteScalar. Also do yourself a favour and call your forms and text boxes some meaningful.

Comment: My comment is out of topic, but I strongly advise you to correctly name your forms elements. What if you don't write any code for your application for 6 monthes and want to modify it. Will you remember what `textbox1`, `Form1` `button42` etc... refers to?

Comment: @PalleDue thank you for your advice I appreciate it. actually I named them in a meaningfull my self but I thought I have to change those names to these for simplicity

Comment: @Cid thank you for your advice and your care. I actually changed my real names to these in order them to be simple... I guess I was wrong... thank you

Answer (score 2):

> textbox1 = Max value of TotalCostColumn.value

If that's your requirement then why not build the query as per like

```
SELECT max(TotalCostColumn) FROM InvoiceTable where id = @id
```

And then instead of using `ExecuteReader()` you should call `ExecuteScalar()` which would return a single value

Answer (score 1):

This is how you'd get the Max value with ExecuteScalar:

```
string selectQuery = "SELECT MAX(TotalCostColumn) FROM InvoiceTable where id = @id";
var sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(selectQuery, sqlcon);
var result = sqlcmd.ExecuteScalar();
return int.Parse(result.ToString());
```

MAX will ensure you only get one row from the table.
To get the latest value, you'd have to sort the table (I assume there's a transaction date) and add `TOP 1` to get only the first row. (Although ExecuteScalar will ignore everything except the first field of the top row but there's no point returning data you don't need)

There are two ways to get the second row. One is to use a datareader and skip over the first row. The other is with SQL:

```
SELECT TOP 1 FROM 
(
  SELECT TOP 2 TotalCost FROM InvoiceTable where id = @id ORDER BY TotalCost DESC
) ORDER BY TotalCost ASC
```

Here the inner query gets two rows of data sorted with the largest item first, and the outer query picks the lower value of the two.

Comment: it underlined the result in `Parse(result);`and  threw this error `cannot convert from object to string` when I used your first code block

Comment: @absolute455 - sorry, I've updated my answer to 'int.Parse(result.ToString());' Also, I'm only guessing that you want an 'int' - a cost could be 'decimal'.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a stored procedure which accepts the value of the id

stored procedure is defined as follows

```
create proc selectmax(@id int)
as begin
select max(TotalCostColumn) FROM InvoiceTable where id = @id
end
```

and call it as below using **Disconnected Model so sqlcon.open() is not Required**

```
SqlCommand sqlcmd = new SqlCommand(selectmax, sqlcon);
sqlcmd.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure
SqlDataAdapter adapter= new SqlDataAdapter(sqlcmd);
      DataSet value=new DataSet();
adapter.Fill(value);
```

This is the implementation using **Ado.net Disconnected Model**